# Monitoring packets going in and out of an application

Tags: udp, packets

I'm building a VoIP application using the TeamSpeak 3 SDK.  Is there any way to view the UDP packets going in and out of the server/client applications?

Answer (score 0):

Any packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (formerly [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)) can do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't tell what I'm looking at.  I need to see UDP packets belonging to my application.  I tried applying the (udp.port 9987) filter, but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?